# MySQL aggregate select query returning incorrect data

Tags: mysql, sql, select, aggregate-functions

I have the following code:

```
SELECT gl.account_description AS invoice_total, COUNT(ili.invoice_id) AS total_invoice, 
    SUM(ili.line_item_amount) AS total_convert
FROM general_ledger_accounts gl JOIN
     invoice_line_items ili 
     ON gl.account_number = ili.account_number JOIN
     invoices i
     ON ili.invoice_id = i.invoice_id
GROUP BY gl.account_description, i.invoice_date, ili.account_number
HAVING i.invoice_date BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-06-30' AND
      COUNT(ili.account_number) > 1
ORDER BY account_description DESC;
```

In my query I am supposed to have 10 rows of data returned and I'm only having 7 return and none of them with the correct information. What I should have returning is the account_description column from the general_ledger_accounts table, a count of the items in the invoice_line_items table, a sum of the line_item_amount columns in the invoice_line_items table that have the same account number. It should only be searching within invoices between the dates '2014-04-01' and '2014-06-30'. I'm supposed to join in the invoices table.

Can anyone see what it is that I'm doing wrong in my syntax to get the wrong results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you want a `WHERE` clause and not a `HAVING` clause for filtering on the dates -- and to remove the date from the `GROUP BY` (you are not selecting it):

```
SELECT gl.account_description AS invoice_total,
       COUNT(*) AS total_invoice, 
       SUM(ili.line_item_amount) AS total_convert
FROM general_ledger_accounts gl JOIN
     invoice_line_items ili 
     ON gl.account_number = ili.account_number JOIN
     invoices i
     ON ili.invoice_id = i.invoice_id
WHERE i.invoice_date BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-06-30'
GROUP BY gl.account_description, ili.account_number
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY account_description DESC;
```

I don't know if there are other issues.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want to remove columns `i.invoice_date` and `ili.account_number` from the `group by` clause. Otherwise, you get one record per distinct values of these three columns, which does not seem to be what you want.

Accordingly, you should move the filter on the dates to the `where` clause:

```
SELECT 
    gl.account_description AS invoice_total, 
    COUNT(ili.invoice_id) AS total_invoice, 
    SUM(ili.line_item_amount) AS total_convert
FROM general_ledger_accounts gl 
INNER JOIN invoice_line_items ili 
    ON gl.account_number = ili.account_number 
INNER JOIN invoices i 
    ON ili.invoice_id = i.invoice_id
WHERE 
    i.invoice_date >= '2014-04-01' 
    AND i.invoice_date < '2014-07-01'
GROUP BY gl.account_description
HAVING COUNT(ili.account_number) > 1
ORDER BY g1.account_description DESC;
```

Note that I modified the condition on the dates to use half-open intervals: this way, you don't have to worry about whether the last month has 30 or 31 days (or 28, or 29...); this would also smoothly handle the time part of the dates, if any.